# How to subtract value from cell when click enter?

Tags: excel

Is there any way to activate function in excel when user press enter after adding value.?
for example I want to execute `=(A3-A4)` each time user enter a new value to A4 cell and press enter

Comment: You will need a vba in a Worksheet_Change() Event.

Comment: Can you clarify? You have a formula,`=A3-A4` in a cell, let's say `B1`.  When a user changes the value in `A4`, the formula does **not** recalculate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to put the following subroutine in the `ThisWorkbook` excel object in VBA (accessible by pressing Alt +F11):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A4")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Value = Range("A3").Value - Target.Value
    End if
End Sub
```

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) for some more information relating to the `Worksheet_Change` event.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to go to File > Options > Formulas and set Calculations options > Workbook Calculation to manual.

Then tell your users to hit F9 to show the result.

Comment: I think he wants to switch it to Automatic, if it's not recalculating each time a value in `A4` changes, unless I misread his issue.

Comment: In that case, follow the instructions above and select "Automatic" and it should do that.  I was thinking he(?) wanted the recalculation to wait until a user did something manually.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're saying - that makes sense too. Either way, this should do it methinks.